# Simple Calculator in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, calculator

I am trying to create a simple calculator using bash script. The main issue being faced is that it is not asking for a second operand for any arithmetic operation. Also, it is not working for negative digits as operand for arithmetic operation. Please find below script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Display user instructions
echo "Welcome to the Simple Calculator"
echo "Instructions:"
echo "Enter operand: Any digit, MR, MC, Clear (C), Off (X)"
echo "Enter operator: +, -, *, /, MS, M+, MC, Clear (C), Off (X)"
echo "------------------------------------------"

# Initialize variables
result=0
memory=0

while true; do
    # Start an infinite loop to keep the calculator running

    # Prompt for operand
    read -p "Enter operand: " input_operand
    # Use 'read' to get user input for operand and store it in 'input_operand'

    case "$input_operand" in
        [0-9]*) operand="$input_operand";;
        # If input_operand is a digit, assign it to the 'operand' variable
        "MR") operand="$result";;
        # If input_operand is "MR", use the previous result as the operand
        "MC") memory=0; echo "0 -> M"; continue;;
        # If input_operand is "MC", clear the memory and display the message
        "C") result=0; echo "results cleared"; continue;;
        # If input_operand is "C", clear the result and display the message
        "X") echo "Good bye."; exit 0;;
        # If input_operand is "X", exit the script with a farewell message
        *) echo "Invalid input. Please re-enter operand."; continue;;
        # For any other input, display an error message and continue to the next iteration
    esac

    # Prompt for operator
    read -p "Enter operator: " operator
    # Use 'read' to get user input for the operator and store it in 'operator'

    case "$operator" in
        "+") result=$((result + operand));;
        # If the operator is "+", perform addition
        "-") result=$((result - operand));;
        # If the operator is "-", perform subtraction
        "*") result=$((result * operand));;
        # If the operator is "*", perform multiplication
        "/")
            if [ "$operand" -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "Can't divide by zero. Please re-enter divisor."
                continue
            else
                result=$((result / operand))
            fi
            # If the operator is "/", handle division with a check for division by zero
            ;;
        "MS") memory="$result"; echo "$result -> M";;
        # If the operator is "MS", store the result in memory and display a message
        "M+") memory=$((memory + result));;
        # If the operator is "M+", add the result to the memory
        "MR") operand="$memory";;
        # If the operator is "MR", use the value from memory as the operand
        "MC") memory=0; echo "0 -> M";;
        # If the operator is "MC", clear the memory and display a message
        "C") result=0; echo "results cleared";;
        # If the operator is "C", clear the result and display a message
        "X") echo "Good bye."; exit 0;;
        # If the operator is "X", exit the script with a farewell message
        *) echo "Invalid operator. Please re-enter operator."; continue;;
        # For any other input, display an error message and continue to the next iteration
    esac

    echo "$result $operator $operand = $result"
    # Display the result of the current operation
done
```

Following is the example of incorrect output:

```
Welcome to the Simple Calculator
Instructions:
Enter operand: Any digit, MR, MC, Clear (C), Off (X)
Enter operator: +, -, *, /, MS, M+, MC, Clear (C), Off (X)
------------------------------------------
Enter operand: 3
Enter operator: *
0 * 3 = 0
Enter operand: 4
Enter operator: +
4 + 4 = 4
Enter operand:
```

Following is an example sequence of the correct expected output:

```
$ ./calc
[ *** User instructions displayed *** ]
Enter operand: 3
Enter operator: +
Enter operand: 4
3 + 4 = 7
Enter operator: -
Enter operand: 12
7 - 12 = -5
Enter operator: MS
-5 -> M
Enter operator: *
Enter operand: 3
-5 * 3 = -15
Enter operator: C
results cleared
Enter operand: MR
M -> -5
Enter operator: *
Enter operand: MR
M -> -5
-5 * -5 = 25
Enter operator: M+
25 + -5 = 20 -> M
Enter operator: /
Enter operand: 0
Can't divide by zero. Please re-enter divisor.
Enter operand: 0
Can't divide by zero. Please re-enter divisor.
Enter operand: -6
25 / -6 = -4
Enter operator: +
Enter operand: C
results cleared
Enter operand: -9
Enter operator: k
Sorry, k, is not a valid operator. Please re-enter operator.
Enter operator: MC
0 -> M
Enter operator: +
Enter operand: 3
-9 + 3 = -6
Enter operator: X
Good bye.
```

Update 1: I have modified the original script based on the high-level pseudo-code design provided in one of the comments. However, it is still showing incorrect output.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Display user instructions
echo "Welcome to the Simple Calculator"
echo "Instructions:"
echo "Enter operand: Any digit, MR, MC, Clear (C), Off (X)"
echo "Enter operator: +, -, *, /, MS, M+, MC, Clear (C), Off (X)"
echo "------------------------------------------"

# Initialize variables
result=0
memory=0

# Function to get an operand
get_operand() {
    read -p "Enter operand: " input_operand
    case "$input_operand" in
        [0-9]*) operand="$input_operand";;
        "MR") operand="$result";;
        "MC") memory=0; echo "0 -> M";;
        "C") result=0; echo "results cleared";;
        "X") echo "Good bye."; exit 0;;
        *) echo "Invalid input. Please re-enter operand."
           get_operand;;
    esac
}

# Function to get an operator
get_operator() {
    read -p "Enter operator: " operator
    case "$operator" in
        "+"|"-"|"*"|"/") ;;
        "MS") memory="$result"; echo "$result -> M";;
        "M+") memory=$((memory + result));;
        "MR") operand="$memory";;
        "MC") memory=0; echo "0 -> M";;
        "C") result=0; echo "results cleared";;
        "X") echo "Good bye."; exit 0;;
        *) echo "Invalid operator. Please re-enter operator."
           get_operator;;
    esac
}

# Initial operand entry
get_operand

while true; do
    get_operator
    if [ "$operator" == "MS" ] || [ "$operator" == "M+" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    get_operand

    case "$operator" in
        "+") result=$((result + operand));;
        "-") result=$((result - operand));;
        "*") result=$((result * operand));;
        "/")
            if [ "$operand" -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "Can't divide by zero. Please re-enter divisor."
                get_operand
            else
                result=$((result / operand))
            fi
            ;;
    esac

    echo "$result $operator $operand = $result"
done
```

Following is the incorrect output:

```
Welcome to the Simple Calculator
Instructions:
Enter operand: Any digit, MR, MC, Clear (C), Off (X)
Enter operator: +, -, *, /, MS, M+, MC, Clear (C), Off (X)
------------------------------------------
Enter operand: 3
Enter operator: +
Enter operand: 4
4 + 4 = 4
Enter operator:
```

Update 2: I have added the rest of the functionality based on the approach provided by @Ed Morton in the comments. Here's the complete script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Initialize variables
result=0
memory=0

# Function to get an operand
get_operand() {
    local input
    while true; do
        read -p "Enter operand: " input
        case "$input" in
            [0-9]*) echo "$input"; break;;
            "MR") echo "$result"; break;;
            "MC") memory=0; echo "0 -> M";;
            "C") result=0; echo "results cleared";;
            "X") echo "Good bye."; exit 0;;
            *) echo "Invalid input. Please re-enter operand."
        esac
    done
}

# Function to get an operator
get_operator() {
    local input
    while true; do
        read -p "Enter operator: " input
        case "$input" in
            "+"|"-"|"*"|"/") echo "$input"; break;;
            "MS") memory="$result"; echo "$result -> M";;
            "M+") memory=$((memory + result));;
            "MR") echo "$memory"; break;;
            "MC") memory=0; echo "0 -> M";;
            "C") result=0; echo "results cleared";;
            "X") echo "Good bye."; exit 0;;
            *) echo "Invalid operator. Please re-enter operator."
        esac
    done
}

# Initial operand entry
result=$(get_operand)

while true; do
    operator=$(get_operator)

    operand=$(get_operand)

    prev_result="$result"
    case "$operator" in
        "+") result=$((result + operand));;
        "-") result=$((result - operand));;
        "*") result=$((result * operand));;
        "/") 
            if [ "$operand" -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "Can't divide by zero. Please re-enter divisor."
                continue
            fi
            result=$((result / operand))
            ;;
    esac

    echo "$prev_result $operator $operand = $result"
done
```

But now it is displaying incorrect result of the operations other than the arithmetic operations. Following incorrect output is showed.

```
Enter operand: 3
Enter operator: +
Enter operand: 4
3 + 4 = 7
Enter operator: -
Enter operand: 12
7 - 12 = -5
Enter operator: MS
Enter operator: *
Enter operand: 3
-5 -5 -> M
* 3 = -5
Enter operator: C
Enter operator: C
Enter operator: MR
Enter operand:
```

It is expected to be according to the above shared example sequence (not exhaustive testing) of the correct expected output.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: The first example was related to the original question. The second example was shared after I modified the script as per recommendations shared by @markp-fuso in the comments section.

Answer (score 2):

Current problem appears to be related to some incomplete logic in terms of when to ask for a new `operator` vs a new `operand`.

Without trying to review all possible combinations of `operand` + `operator`, while using OP's 'correct expected output' as a template, it looks to me like the general flow is something like:

- start by getting an operand then go into a loop with the following steps ...
- get an operator
- based on the operator either *a)* get another operator or *b)* get a new operand
- if we opt to get a new operand then perform the desired operator/operation

A high-level pseudo-code design:

```
get_operand

while true
do
    get_operator
    process_operator
        if operator == 'M+' || 'MC' then continue
    get_operand
    process_operand
    perform_operation_on_operand
done
```

Obviously replace the `get_*` and `process_*` calls with the `read / case` blocks (or possibly push into a pair of functions to make the `while true` loop a bit cleaner?).

Comment: I have modified the original script based on the high-level pseudo-code design provided in one of the comments. However, it is still showing incorrect output. Please check updated part in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I stripped down your code to just get `+` working. Try this:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Initialize variables
result=0

# Function to get an operand
get_operand() {
    local input
    read -p "Enter operand: " input
    case "$input" in
        [0-9]*) ;;
        *) echo "Invalid input. Please re-enter operand."
           input=$(get_operand);;
    esac
    echo "$input"
}

# Function to get an operator
get_operator() {
    local input
    read -p "Enter operator: " input
    case "$input" in
        "+"|"-"|"*"|"/") ;;
        *) echo "Invalid operator. Please re-enter operator."
           input=$(get_operator);;
    esac
    echo "$input"
}

# Initial operand entry
result=$(get_operand)

while true; do
    operator=$(get_operator)

    operand=$(get_operand)

    prev_result="$result"
    case "$operator" in
        "+") result=$((result + operand));;
    esac

    echo "$prev_result $operator $operand = $result"
done
```

and you'll see it works:

```
$ ./tst.sh
Enter operand: 4
Enter operator: +
Enter operand: 4
4 + 4 = 8
Enter operator:
```

Now add the rest of your functionality onto it.

FWIW for simplicity and clarity I'd use a loop instead of recursion in your `get_...` functions, e.g.:

```
get_operand() {
    local input
    while [[ -z "$input" ]]; do
        read -p "Enter operand: " input
        case "$input" in
            [0-9]*) ;;
            *) echo "Invalid input. Please re-enter operand."
               input=""
        esac
    done
    echo "$input"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ed Morton. I have added the rest of the functionality based on the approach provided by you. But now it is displaying incorrect result of the operations other than the arithmetic operations. Please check 'Update 2' part of the question.

Comment: You should accept an answer and then ask a new question rather than keep adding updates onto your existing question. A question is to help people with a specific problem, not to help them with every issue they might encounter while creating a script and [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are discouraged.